# Remove specific div using keys

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, key

I have a component that has 2 divs by default and there's a `Add Option` to add additional divs. (Maximum of 2 new divs can be added). I'm maintaining states to add or remove the added divs. I'm increasing the value i have set in my state when i click the 'Add option' button and decreasing the value when i click 'remove' button to add or remove the divs.(each added div has a remove button) My problem is in this method only the last div is getting removed when i click 'remove' button of either added divs and not the one i want to remove. How to remove the div using keys so i can i remove the exact div i want?

My code

**html**

```
for (let i = 3; i <= this.state.maxImage; i++) {
      list.push(<div key={i}>{this.state.addOption > i &&
        <div className="txt_vote_bar_div">

          <div className="full_div right0" style={{width: '15px', height: '15px'}} id="close"
               onClick={this.removetextpoll}>
            <i className="fa fa-times float_right"/>
          </div>

          <Field name={`inputName${i}`} component="input" type="text" className="vote_input" placeholder={`Option ${i}`}
                 maxLength={textPollMaxLength}/>
        </div>}
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>


                <div className="txt_vote_bar_div">
                  <Field name="inputName1" component="input" type="text" className="vote_input" placeholder="Option 1"/>
                </div>

                <div className="txt_vote_bar_div">
                  <Field name="inputName2" component="input" type="text" className="vote_input" placeholder="Option 2"/>
                </div>

                {list}


                {this.state.addOption === 5 ? null :
                  <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" id="txt_vote_bar_div_create"
                       onClick={this.addOption}>
                    <span className="horiz_center font_bold" id="addOption">Add Option</span>
                  </div>
                }
         </form>
```

**JS**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      addOption: 3,
      maxImage: 4,
      optionBtn: true,

    };
    this.addOption = this.addOption.bind(this);
    this.removetextpoll = this.removetextpoll.bind(this);

  }

    addOption() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          addOption: ++prevState.addOption
        }));

      }

      removetextpoll() {

        this.setState((prevState) => ({

          addOption: --prevState.addOption

        }));

      }
```

Comment: send to your function current div with removetextpoll(id).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better just to add options description in state like this

```
this.state = {
  addOption: 3,
  maxImage: 4,
  optionBtn: true,
  fields: [
    { id: 1, name: 'SOME_NAME1', value: 'SOME_VALUE1', placeholder: 'SOME_PLACEHOLDER_VAL1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'SOME_NAME2', value: 'SOME_VALUE2', placeholder: 'SOME_PLACEHOLDER_VAL2' }
  ]
};
```

and render/add/remove items by state.fields array contents.

So you may remove items in this way

```
handleDeleteClick(idToDelete, event) {
  /*delete from state by id*/
}

render() {
  return(
    this.state.fields.map((field) => {
      return (
        <Field 
          key={ field.id }
          name={ field.name }
          value={ field.value }
          placeholder={ field.placeholder }
          onDeleteClick={ this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this, field.id)}
        />)
    })
  );
}
```